# Alert fails in UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I'd like to get an alert from the server inside of an AJAX call in an `Update Panel` but something is blocking the `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write` from firing on the client.

Here's a very simple aspx body content

```xml
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <!-- DropDownList doesn't work here -->
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">First</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Second</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</form>
```

And here's where I'm handling it in VB

```vb
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim alertMsg As String
    Dim alertScript As String
    'DO OTHER STUFF HERE
    alertMsg = String.Format("You Selected {0}", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
    alertScript = String.Format("<script type= text/javascript>alert('{0}');</script>", alertMsg)

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(alertScript)

End Sub
```

Both times the vb code will fire, but it only scripts an alert message when called outside the the UpdatePanel, instead of inside it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register the script using [ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) since you are using updatepanel. Try the following code. It should work:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim alertMsg As String
    Dim alertScript As String
    'DO OTHER STUFF HERE
    alertMsg = String.Format("You Selected {0}", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
    alertScript = String.Format("<script type= text/javascript>alert('{0}');</script>", alertMsg)

    'register script on startup
    ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "Alert", alertScript);
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write` is not working inside the UpdatePanel and maybe you also have javascript errors.

The reason is that the UpdatePanel is prepare on an xml struct a part of the page, and send it to the client with ajax - the `Response.Write` from the other side is direct try to write on the browser page - but here we have ajax call, we do not have direct access to the page buffer.

To solve your issue, use a Literal inside the UpdatePanel, and render your message on that Literal - but again, you can not render script and expect to run after the update panel.

To make your script run after the update panel, [register your script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207(v=vs.100).aspx)